# How do i write a query to show spec id and number of staff with that speciality

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a query to show the speciality Id, Number of staff with that speciality
 of those specialties with more than 2 staff, Name the new column Num with Speciality. Display in ascending order of Num with Speciality

```
COLUMN COUNT(specid) HEADING "Num with Speciality"
SELECT id.specid, 
       count(specname) "Num with Speciality"
FROM staff_speciality id,speciality
WHERE staff_speciality > 2
ORDER BY specid  ASC;
```

```
SQL> describ staff_speciality
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STAFFID                                   NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 SPECID                                             CHAR(4)
 DATEQUALIFIED                             NOT NULL DATE
 VALIDDATE                                          DATE
 DETAILS                                            VARCHAR2(100)

SQL> describ staff_speciality
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STAFFID                                   NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 SPECID                                             CHAR(4)
 DATEQUALIFIED                             NOT NULL DATE
 VALIDDATE                                          DATE
 DETAILS                                            VARCHAR2(100)
```

Comment: update your question add  a clear data sample and the expcted  result  ..

Comment: show us both the table!!

Comment: SQL> describ staff_speciality
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STAFFID                                   NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 SPECID                                             CHAR(4)
 DATEQUALIFIED                             NOT NULL DATE
 VALIDDATE                                          DATE
 DETAILS                                            VARCHAR2(100)

Comment: SQL> describ staff_speciality
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 STAFFID                                   NOT NULL CHAR(2)
 SPECID                                             CHAR(4)
 DATEQUALIFIED                             NOT NULL DATE
 VALIDDATE                                          DATE
 DETAILS                                            VARCHAR2(100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY LIKE Below by using having

```
SELECT SPECID,
       count(*) "Num with Speciality"
FROM staff_speciality 
GROUP BY SPECID
HAVING count(*) > 2
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE SPECIALITY
(SpecId CHAR(4)    PRIMARY KEY,
SpecName  VARCHAR(25),
SpecNotes  VARCHAR(100));

Comment: CREATE TABLE STAFF_SPECIALITY
(StaffId   CHAR(2)   PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES STAFF(StaffId),
SpecId CHAR(4) REFERENCES SPECIALITY(SpecID),
DateQualified Date NOT NULL,
ValidDate  DATE,
Details VARCHAR(100));